# Covert S3 Buffer Data to PDF File

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, amazon-s3

I am using an express route to get the s3 object via the AWS SDK:

```
router.get('/myRoute', (req, res) => {
const s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'});
s3.getObject({Bucket: 'my-bucket', Key: 'my-key'},
    function (error, data) {
        if (error != null) {
            // console.log(error)
            return res.send("Failed to retrieve an object: " + error.message);
        } else {
            console.log("data: ", data)
            return res.json(data)

        }
    });
});
```

The console output from above is:

```
 data:  {
  AcceptRanges: 'bytes',
  LastModified: 2022-06-06T01:29:41.000Z,
  ContentLength: 327626,
  ETag: '"..."',
  VersionId: '....dy',
  ContentType: 'application/pdf',
  Metadata: {},
  TagCount: 1,
  Body: <Buffer 25 50 44 46 2d 31 2e ... 327576 more bytes>
}
```

The react client code looks like this:

```
    const response = await fetch("/api/aws/brochure")
.then(res => res.json())
.then((data) => {
    console.log(typeof(data.Body.data))
    const fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([new int8Array(data.Body.data).buffer]));

    //Open the URL on new Window
    const pdfWindow = window.open();
    pdfWindow.location.href = fileURL;   
});
```

The result is:
[image]

Comment: Set the type as `application/pdf` while creating the Blob object.

Comment: That worked thanks! Care to put that as the answer and I'll mark it as correct?

Comment: Thanks for confirmation. I've posted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While initializing the blob object, you should specify the type which is a string indicating the MIME type of the data contained in the buffer.

So to create the blob, use below signature

```
var blob = new Blob([new int8Array(data.Body.data).buffer], type: "application/pdf");
```

Read more about blob [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob).